# Reusable pictures of Chinese factories in the 1930~1940s

Tags: data-request, historical, industry, photographs, china

I am looking for reusable pictures of Chinese factories in the 1930s and 1940s.

The closest categories I could find on Wikimedia Commons don't seem to contain anything relevant:

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Science_and_technology_in_China
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:History_of_the_Republic_of_China (PRC is 1949)
- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Buildings_in_China_by_year_of_completion

By "reusable" I mean they can be uploaded to Wikimedia Commons.

Comment: http://www.loc.gov/pictures/search/?q=chinese%20factory

Answer (score 3):

Here are some of my findings.. no one source, lots of looking all over the net:

1. Search for "factory" on http://www.asu.edu/lib/archives/smedforeign.htm

   > "Chinese factory workers have spiritual  faces--faces filled with suffering."
   >   1930s Photographer: Agnes Smedley Agnes Smedley Collection
   >   MSS-122 Vol. 39
2. http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:China_Motor_Corporation_top_crew.jpg

   > Top managers, chief engineers, and American consultants in front of
   >   the China Motor Corporation. China Motor Corporation was the first
   >   Chinese factory of manufacturing jet engines. It was established with
   >   American assistance. World War II, in Kuichow (current Guizhou),
   >   China.
3. 1950s and not a photograph but: https://www.flickr.com/photos/chinesepostersnet/5099136754

   > Emulation in the Patriotic production campaign  Designer: Huang Jun
   >   ca. 1950

Comment: I'm afraid #3 is explicitly marked "all rights reserved", and I don't see any signs of usage rules for #1. Only #2 is explicitly marked "public domain."

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth searching [Europeana](http://europeana.eu) or the [Digital Public Library of America](http://dp.la). For DPLA particularly, keep your eye on the left-hand sidebar for lists of collections; you may find a stash you wouldn't otherwise have known existed.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Image Search](https://images.google.com/) provides helpful settings to search for reusable pictures. For a detailed explanation have a look at [Find reusable images of city X with width>2100 pixels](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/962/find-reusable-images-of-city-x-with-width2100-pixels).

Comment: +1 I guess that would be like https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1855&bih=985&q=chinese+factory+1940&oq=chinese+factory+1940 I have checked the first page of results, and have found only images of war, pictures of factories outside of China, and two China factory images that are BY-NC even though I explicitly asked Google Image Search for commercially reusable pictures.

Comment: I agree, there doesn't seem to be much out there that fits your requirements. Another idea would be to ask a native speaker to search in Chinese …

Comment: Great idea! The Chinese word for factory is 工廠, which also happens to be a naval word used in Japanese, which monopolizes Google results...